# How to add number after decimal to the number

Tags: c#, math

I want to take a number with a decimal point and add the numbers after the point to the integer number.

For example:

input: **1.88**

Output: **188**

**Not specifically working with 2 decimal numbers**

Thanks.

Comment: Convert number to string, remove decimal separator from it, and convert back to integer number.

Comment: How about `var value = 1.88m; while ((value - (long)value) != 0) { value *= 10; } return (long)value;`?

Comment: Depending on why you want to do this, simply multiplying by 100 might be the simplest solution. Otherwise it could get murky due to floating point precision (or lack thereof).

Comment: @john - assuming OP works with `decimal`, there shouldn't be floating point precision issues... but you're right, it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: @kosist - that's probably the easiest way, but one should definitely specify the exact culture, so that there are no problems with culture dependent decimal separators. And also beware of thousands separators...

Comment: if you need to get the integer type just multiplay by 100 and then cast it to integer
`int result = (int) yourDicimalValue *100;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by kosist:

```
double input = 1.88;
var inputAsString = input.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var output = inputAsString.Replace(".", "");
//Optional:
var outputAsInt = int.Parse(output);
```

Comment: I think there must some validation regarding the range as converting double to int just by removng the '.' will surely cause overflow in int many trivial cases.

Comment: If overflow is a concern, then you can try parsing as Double for a lot more headroom. It depends on your use case though.